# Spring Boot uses Spring IO implicitly?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-io

I want to get all benefits of Spring IO and Spring Boot. I understood that Spring IO is something larger than Spring Boot. I understood that the main Spring IO concern is about integration, solve conflicts between a lot of frameworks and components with spring platform, and the main concern about Spring Boot is to create a simpler and quicker way to use spring platform, but what I really want to know is: When I'm using just Spring Boot, in all this pom hierarchy, you will be using Spring IO in some level of this heritage of pom structure?

If the answer is no, what is the best way to use both initiatives? Both of them recommend to use a parent pom, or import the pom (using the concept of bom) as dependecy-management. Should I use one as parent and other as bom (importing as dependency management)?

Comment: Take a look at the available [starter poms](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter-poms) and determine which one(s) include the dependancies you need.

Comment: Also take a look at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438751/what-is-the-relationship-between-spring-boot-and-spring-io  SpringIO is really just for dependancy management, which you may not need, where Spring Boot handles dependancies and runtimes.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, Spring IO and Spring Boot have different focus, but they play nicely together.

In fact, Spring IO bom **inherits** from Spring Boot's one, so it is sufficient to Spring IO as parent and you can have all benefits of both (like mvn sensible defaults). For more detail see [my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200261/should-you-use-the-parent-if-you-are-using-the-spring-platform-bom/28201112#28201112).

Only "disadvantage" of using Spring IO is that it might be a little bit "behind" of latest Spring Boot version but if you are okey with it you can enjoy more managed dependencies.